# i get spaces interpretted as boxes by the web broswer for the font "bebas" how to work around this

Tags: css, fonts

Basically, this font type interprets spaces as boxes, for some reason.  How do I work around this without having to change the font type?

Comment: Please show some code and/or a screenshot of what happens

Answer (score 0):

well you will HAVE to add spans or other tags. I do not think there is anyways except by using php (Which I do not know). you will have to use

```
@font-face {
font-family: font-name;
src: url('/*url here*/');}
.my-font{
font-family: font-name;
}
```

and spans

```
<span class='my-font'>(Char that makes box?)</space>
```

Comment: how would php help in this instance?

Comment: OHHH i c, use php to generate the text, and have it place the span tags? gotcha.

Comment: to say the truth... I have no idea.